# Getting the filename of a jar-with-dependencies as a variable

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using the `maven-assembly-plugin` to package my jar file with dependencies, which works fine and correctly generates a jar file. The output file from this is specified with `finalName`:

```
<plugin>
    <!--Many lines omitted-->
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>MyFinalJar-${project.version}</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, I need to access this `finalName` in another plugin, which does some packaging of the jar file. I have the `${project.build.finalName}` variable, but that **doesn't** give me the jar-with-dependencies, it just gives me the plain jar that I don't want.

How can I access this final jar filename without repeating myself?

Comment: The finalName is not the name which you can use to reference it somewhere else...The decriptor contains an `<id>xxx</id>` in result the name you can use to reference is your `<artifactId>aid</artifactId>` plus the id as classifier `aid-VERSION-xxx` which can reference that artifact. If you are talking about `jar-with-dependencies` so you are using the predefined descriptor..which means you need to use `artifact-VERSION-jar-with-dependencies`...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top of your pom file declare:

```
<properties>
  <finalproject.name>someprojectname</finalproject.name>
</properties>
```

and then use it everywhere else using:

```
${finalproject.name}
```

for example:

```
<configuration>
    <finalName>${finalproject.name}</finalName>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This does work, but I didn't expect I'd have to declare another variable. I was hoping to access the internal variable of the `maven-assembly-plugin`

Comment: @Miguel If it is not something it intentionally expose out, why do you think you can and you should use it?